# How to push multidimensional array to another multidimensional array in foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

When I query in my table and found some rows in my variable in print by foeach loop. Now I want to add another array like array('key' => 'value') to each row just like add another field in table and print by foreach loop

```
$data = $q -> fetachAll()
$values = array();
foreach($data as $key => $rows) {
    $margeArray = array_merge($rows, array("key" => 'value'));
    array_push($values, $margeArray);
}
/*==Print Here===*/
   foreach($values as $keys => $rows) {
       echo $rows['key'];
   }
```

How I do that?

Comment: Its simple lets say you have an array $arr['key'] => 'value';

Now you have another array and you want to merge it. 

`$arr['key1'] = $new_arr

and then

$arr['key1']['test'] = $another_new_arr`

Comment: Can you post sample input and expected output?

Comment: I have 2 tables. One is Institutes and another Leaders and relation with institute ID in Leaders Table. But I want to show with one method

"Institute Name (Total number of Leader)"

Comment: you should include your expected output

Comment: My expected output  "Institute Name (Total number of Leader)"  by one medthod return array values #Rohit Kumar

Comment: Can you print_r($data)?